# I want extract from Json and count in HQL

Tags: sql, hive, extract

I want extract from Json and count in HQL
JSON is like

```
{
    "online_pay": 1,
    "is_settle": 1,
    "period": "00:00-23:59",
    "policy_detail": [{
        "price": 10.0,
        "discounts": [{
            "agent_charge": 0.0,
            "code": 1,
            "mt_charge": 0.0,
            "type": "default",
            "poi_charge": 1.0,
            "discount": 1.0
        }]
    }, {
        "price": 15.0,
        "discounts": [{
            "agent_charge": 0.0,
            "code": 1,
            "mt_charge": 0.0,
            "type": "default",
            "poi_charge": 2.0,
            "discount": 2.0
        }]
    }, {
        "price": 20.0,
        "discounts": [{
            "agent_charge": 0.0,
            "code": 1,
            "mt_charge": 0.0,
            "type": "default",
            "poi_charge": 3.0,
            "discount": 3.0
        }]
    }, 
    "type": 2
}
```

I tried

```
regexp_extract(detail,'price\"\:[0-9]+')
```

but it's only bring me       price": 10.0
I want then all

Comment: policy_detail is an array. Create table with JsonSerDe, describe structure then query array and explode. regexp is not a solution for the this task